# What’s asbestos look like on heating vents?

Tags: hvac, asbestos

I’m repainting my heating register vents and noticed something on the ductwork I didn’t see before. Pics attached. Judging from a google search, it looks like the section of ductwork that connects to the baseboard is wrapped in asbestos.

I can’t find it on any other parts of my ductwork in the basement. Just on the pieces that connect to the baseboard register vents.

Should I be concerned? No plans to do any remodeling anytime soon. Is it worrisome that it’s so accessible to get at? And why would it only be used on this parts of the ducting?

[image: View of duct/vent with vent cover removed]

[image: view of same duct from the basement where it goes into the baseboard of the room above]

Answer (score -1):

I would say that looks like asbestos that I have done remediation on the white fibrous and board like material usually are I can’t tell the maroon color it could have been painted to encapsulate it.

The only way to know for sure is to test but this looks like it.

Comment: Thanks. The photo with the maroon is a bit hard to understand. The maroon is actually the boards for the first floor. There’s a small bit of the white wrapper that can be seen in that photo. Wondering if there’s a reason only a small section of the vent was wrapped in it. It looks like just the piece that went to the baseboard vent has the white wrap on it.

Comment: Ok I see it now yes they used to insulate metal to wood with asbestos sheet material round pipes were dense but very fibrous if not painted usually from a white to a grayish color, people started paint it to encapsulate it of if in the open to keep it from looking so dirty, if you have a gas water heater or boiler it may still be wrapped up in the attic but people started removing it in the late 60’s and 70’s that I know of just using dust masks , today respirators. Tyvek suits rubber gloves and boots and wet it down prior to moving it if it is legal in your area some states it is not.

Comment: Looks like more down votes with no reason 2 on this question. Possibly because it was still open ?